# Open a txt file when a button clicked in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a log file in my project. This file is a text file (.txt). Is there a way to open this file when a button clicked without using the [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tool?

Note that I'm using VB.NET 2010.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\FileName.txt"

If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
    Process.Start(FILE_NAME)
Else
    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
End If
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple example:

```
 Public Class OpenTextFile

    Private Sub OpenTextFile_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenBUT_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenBUT.Click
        'OpenBUT_Click the text file
        Process.Start("C:\File Name.txt")
    End Sub
End Class
```